# JAVA - Method/Function non detected

Tags: java, methods, undefined, program-entry-point

I wrote a script in Java and everything is fine except a small detail. Java doesn't recoognize my function "ajouter" whereas it is well defined.
There are 2 Java files : Conteneur and Main (for the "public static void main").
Here the 2 source codes :
Conteneur :

```
 public static double[] ajouter(int Valeur, double Tableau[]){
    double x;
    for(int i =0; i<Tableau.length; i++)
    {
        x = Tableau[i];
        if (Double.isNaN(x) == true && i == 10){
            System.out.println("Tableau plein");
            return Tableau;}
        if( Double.isNaN(x) == true){
            Tableau[i]=Valeur;
        }

    }
    return Tableau;
}
```

Main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double Tableau[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    System.out.println(ajouter(6, Tableau));
}
```

At the line where it is written : "System.out.println(ajouter(6,Tableau));", JAVA displays "method ajouter(int, double[]) is undefined for the type main".

Can you help me please ?

Thank you in advance !

Best regards !

Comment: Try `Conteneur.ajouter(6, Tableau)` -- you will need to specify the class. Alternatively, you can do a static import.

Comment: Note: `== true` is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've imported the `Conteneur` class, in your main method you need to call it like this:

```
System.out.println(Conteneur.ajouter(6,Tableau));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `import static Conteneur.*` in your `Main` class, in order to reference `Conteneur`'s static methods without referencing and importing `Conteneur` itself.

So, either way:

- `import static Conteneur.* // and no further change`
- `import Conteneur // reference "ajouter" with Conteneur.ajouter`

You also want to:

- Use an IDE
- Use English in your code, unless your project is **only** ever going to be maintained by French-speaking people (and still, I'd use English anyway)
- Use proper variable naming, e.g. not CamelCase but camelBack

Answer (score 0):

Should include class which defines static method.
Conteneur.ajouter(6, Tableau)

Answer (score 0):

The following correctly prints the table `Tableau`.

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double Tableau[]={1,2,3,4,5};
       // System.out.println(Conteneur.ajouter(6,Tableau));
        Conteneur.ajouter(6,Tableau);
        for (int i=0; i<Tableau.length; i++){
            System.out.println(Tableau[i]);
        }
        }

}
```

However, `Double.isNaN(x)` will always be `false` (because `x` is a `double`) so the value `Valeur` will never be added.